# No suitable user-defined conversion from "cv::Scalar" to "CvScalar" exists

Tags: c++, image, visual-studio, opencv, visual-c++

I am traying to run old c++ code in pc with this caracteristcs:

- opencv: 3.4.14
- OS: Win 10
- code: c++

An example of the code:

```cpp
CvScalar color = CV_RGB(255, 255, 255);
```

But return the next error:

```cpp
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'cv::Scalar' to 'CvScalar'
```

Comment: don't use obsolete C api!

Comment: It is a code with a hundreds of classes, I can not change all the C api.

Comment: You have to downgrade to OpenCV 2.x as the definition of `CvScalar` and many other things changed with 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
CvScalar color = CV_RGB(255, 255, 255);
```

to this:

```
cv::Scalar color = CV_RGB(255, 255, 255);
```

Comment: CV_RGB is also a blast from the past. make it simply: `cv::Scalar color(255, 255, 255)` (and note, that opencv usue BGR color ordering by default

Answer (score 0):

This is defined in OpenCV 2.3.1

```
typedef struct CvScalar
{
    double val[4];
}

#define CV_RGB( r, g, b )  cvScalar( (b), (g), (r), 0 )
```

And this is defined in OpenCV 4.7

```
#define CV_RGB(r, g, b)  cv::Scalar((b), (g), (r), 0)
```

So, to solve your issue, you could use this function:

```
inline CvScalar to_CvScalar(cv::Scalar s)
{
    CvScalar ret;

    ret.val[0] = s.val[0]; // blue
    ret.val[1] = s.val[1]; // green
    ret.val[2] = s.val[2]; // red
    ret.val[3] = s.val[3]; // alpha

    return ret;
}
```

and change your code this way:

```
CvScalar color = to_CvScalar(CV_RGB(255, 255, 255));
```